# How to "repair" a PDF that opens in Acrobat Reader but not Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, adobe

I have a PDF that won't open in Preview; it gives this error message:

[image]

However, it will open in Acrobat Reader, but cannot be resaved, or saved with a new file name from Reader:

[image]

As I can see all the pages (or most of them at least!) from this PDF, there must be some way to get them into a file that Preview can open. I can do this by copying pages from Reader one-at-a-time, but the PDF has 500 pages.

What is the easiest and cheapest way to export all these pages, and create a new PDF, from Acrobat Reader?

**EDIT:** I'd rather not have to sign up for online Adobe services...

Answer (score 5):

I just had exactly the same problem. A filled-in PDF form from our tax service displays as follows in almost all PDF readers *except* Adobe's:

[image]

Not one of the normal solutions works. Every single macOS-native save-to-pdf or print-to-pdf option from within Acrobat Reader fails with "Saving a PDF file when printing is not supported."

I ended up having to use [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) in one of my VMWare Windows guest images to open the offending PDF 1.7 form and then to print to the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer driver.

A similar driver for macOS which could trick Adobe Reader into thinking that it was just a printer could also work, but I did not have more time to investigate other options.

There's NO reason for Adobe to make it this difficult to export a PDF form to read-only rendered version. Well, it could be because Reader has a truly subpar UI on macOS, so the company has to make use of alternative techniques to retain users.

Comment: How about Apple updating Preview so it can open everything that Adobe does?  That's the real problem.  We all need Adobe to handle docs that Preview cannot.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the **Ghostscript** tools `pdf2ps` & `ps2pdf` from the commandline.

- `pdf2ps input.pdf output.ps` to convert to a PostScript file
- `ps2pdf input.ps output.pdf` to convert to a pdf file

  1. You can install Ghostscript with [homebrew](https://brew.sh)
  2. or use [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html)

The MacTeX way gives you a 3 GB installer that will install by default a ghostscript package & lots of other things like a TeX folder in your `/Applications` folder. This may be overkill for you.
The homebrew way `brew install ghostscript` or `brew install gs` (both do the same thing) installs a much smaller ghostscript package.

Either way you'll end up with the conversion tools.
`pdf2ps` allows you to specify which PS-level you want your output to be in.
`ps2pdf` has 4 variants:

- ps2pdf
- ps2pdf12
- ps2pdf13
- ps2pdf14

From its manpage

```
 - ps2pdf12 will always produce PDF 1.2 output (Acrobat 3-and-later compatible).

 - ps2pdf13 will always produce PDF 1.3 output (Acrobat 4-and-later compatible).

 - ps2pdf14 will always produce PDF 1.4 output (Acrobat 5-and-later compatible).

 - ps2pdf per se currently produces PDF 1.4 output. However, this may change in the future.
```

There's also a `pstopdf` tool installed by Apple that can convert PostScript to pdf. Sometimes the `ps2pdf` tools are unsuccessful and the `pstopdf` tool works.

My experience is:

Convert pdf's with `pdf2ps` and convert the resulting PostScript file to pdf with `pstopdf`. This works the best for me without having to fiddle with the various options that these tools offer.
If you want (or need) to play with these options there is a lot of documentation & you can ask questions on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Great suggestions. It might be worth mentioning that [MacPorts](http://macports.org) can install GhostScript too, in case folks have that installed rather than HomeBrew.

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the PDF from Acrobat Reader and then choose to print to (save as) a PDF. Note - you should not choose Save from the File menu in Acrobat Reader, instead you must choose Print. When asked which printer to print to, you can select to open as a PDF in Preview instead.

Comment: Hi there. This doesn't work. I get the error message: "Saving a PDF file when printing is not supported. Instead, choose File > Save."

Comment: Choose to save as Postscript instead.

Comment: Hi there. That doesn't work either, and gives a similar error code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of online sites that claim to fix a PDF you upload, free or paid, but if it has sensitive content you don't want to share, you'll want a Mac-specific repair tool. Again, there are many sites selling various tools, but here are some that appear to be good products from reputable sellers.

- [Stellar Phoenix Repair for PDF - Mac](https://www.stellarinfo.com/mac-software/pdf-repair-mac.php): $29, free trial available (allows view but not save)
- [VeryPDF PDF Repair for Mac](http://www.verypdf.com/app/pdf-repair-mac/index.html): $29.95, free trial available

Finally, this [Chron.com article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/repair-pdf-file-mac-47754.html) describes how to do this with the free tool [PDF Toolkit](http://pdftoolkit.net/easy_mac/). Excerpt:

1. Download and install the Mac version of the PDF Toolkit.
2. Open the **Terminal** application.
3. Type in `pdftk broken.pdf output fixed.pdf` Replace *broken.pdf* with the file name of your corrupted PDF.
4. Press < Enter > and wait for the toolkit to scan and repair the PDF.
5. Locate the folder of the original PDF file and open the *fixed.pdf* file. This will contain the repaired PDF document and all of the elements it was able to recover.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a trial version of Acrobat to see if any of those options will work.
https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/free-trial-download.html

If saving directly as a PDF file doesn't work Acrobat has an option to save as a Word document which you can then turn back into a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a screenshot of the form, pasting it into Keynote and saving as PDF. Then I could open it with Preview and fill out the parts of the form that weren't working.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me for the PDFs for which Preview gives up with a message that only Adobe Acrobat Reader is allowed to open.

1. In Adobe Acrobat (I have the pro license), export to PS.
2. Using [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/), convert PS to PDF

Notes

- Step 1 above is not available in Adobe Acrobat Reader.
- Trying other formats: converting to Word format did not work
  expectedly in my case while trying to do that with Adobe Acrobat
  Reader, as the formatting went haywire. For PS format, formatting was
  preserved.